# How to split one vector in to multiple vectors with pattern in R

Tags: r

I have a vector and I want to split it into multiple vectors with some pattern. For example:

```
a table x with a vector  of 14 numbers like:
x
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

I want to create a new table with multiple vectors based on above vector

```
n=2,m1=3,m2=4
column n=2, for column1:row=n*m1 and column2: row= n*m2 (Here, the number could be variables)

1   7
2   8
3   9
4   10
5   11
6   12
    13
    14
```

Many thanks

Comment: `n <- 2; split(1:14, rep(1:2, n*3:4))` maybe.

Comment: If by table you mean data.frame, this maybe be almost doing what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380954/wrap-a-2-column-data-frame-in-r

Comment: n <- 2; split(1:14, rep(1:2, n*3:4)). This code does not work. error: Warning message:
In split.default(x, rep(1:2, n * 3:4)) :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable

Comment: Hi snd, for the linked solution looks not what I want. I could not understand the coding. are there simpler solutions?

Comment: @Michale if you see the error "data length is not a multiple of split variable", you should provide example data that mimic your real issue.

Comment: I got what you meant. It works. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi @markus I post a new question with flexible columns case.Hope you can help me out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61858689/how-to-split-one-column-in-to-multiple-columns-with-pattern-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

markus's solution is correct. Many thanks.

```
n <- 2; split(1:14, rep(1:2, n*3:4))
```