# How to split one column in to multiple columns with pattern in R

Tags: r

we know a column x with a vector  of like 21 numbers:

```
x
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
```

If I want to get multiple columns with flexible pattern like :
can set numbers in advance (n could be 3 or 4 or ...):

```
n=3,n1=2,n2=3,n3=2,.... the total number of columns is determined by number n.
column n=3, for column1:row=n*n1 and column2: row= n*n2, column3:row=n*n3 (Here, the number could be variables)
```

Final output is:(this is n=3 case, but my final goal is n could be 4,5...)

```
1   7   16
2   8   17 
3   9   18 
4   10  19
5   11  20 
6   12  21
    13  
    14    
    15
```

If n set as n=2,n1=3,n2=4. The one column number would become 14 c(1:14). (The real practice is I do not know how many columns needed to be created in advance. The column number is input by users).

Then what I what to get n =2 columns:

```
1  7
2  8
3  9
4  10
5  11
6  12
   13
   14
```

I am trying to make the columns created automatically in advance with variables.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create an grouping variable with `rep` and `split`

```
split(df1$x,  rep(1:3, c(6, 9, 6)))
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

#$`2`
#[1]  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15

#$`3`
#[1] 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

---

A function can be created with arguments,  'n', and additional arguments with `...`

```
f1 <- function(dat, n, ...) {

       rgrp <- n * c(...)
       split(dat[[1]][seq_len(sum(rgrp))], rep(seq_len(n), rgrp))
 }

f1(df1, 2, 3, 4)
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

#$`2`
#[1]  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14   



f1(df1, 3, 2, 3, 2)
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

#$`2`
#[1]  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15

#$`3`
#[1] 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

If the user submits a `vector` and we don't have `n`, then get the `n` from the `length` of the vector

```
f1 <- function(dat, vec) {
       n <- length(vec)

       rgrp <- n * vec
       split(dat[[1]][seq_len(sum(rgrp))], rep(seq_len(n), rgrp))
 }

 f1(df1, 3:4)
```

If the user input 'n1', 'n2', we can use `...`

```
 f1 <- function(dat, ...) {
       vec <- c(...)
       n <- length(vec)

       rgrp <- n * vec
       split(dat[[1]][seq_len(sum(rgrp))], rep(seq_len(n), rgrp))
 }

 f1(df1, 3, 4)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = 1:21), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214084/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-how-to-split-one-column-in-to-multiple-columns-wit).